# What is docker --kernel-memory

Tags: linux, docker

Good day , I know that Docker containers are using the host's kernel (which is why containers are considered as lightweight vms) Here the the [source](https://superuser.com/questions/889472/docker-containers-have-their-own-kernel-or-not) . However, after reading Runtime Options part of a docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/)  I met an option called `--kernel-memory`. The doc says

```
The maximum amount of kernel memory the container can use.
```

I didn't understand what it does. My guess is every container will allocate some memory in host's kernel space .If so then what is the reason , isn't it vulnerable for a user process to allocate memory in kernel space  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole CPU/Memory Limitation stuff is using `cgroups`.
You can find all settings performed by `docker run` (either per args or per default) under `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker/<container ID>` for memory or `/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/docker/<container ID>` for cpu.

So the `--kernel-memory`:

**Reading**: `cat memory.kmem.limit_in_bytes`

**Writing**: `sudo -s` `echo 2167483648 > memory.kmem.limit_in_bytes`

And also the benchmarking `memory.kmem.max_usage_in_bytes` and `memory.kmem.usage_in_bytes` which shows (rather selfexplaining) the current usage and the highest usage overall.

### CGroup docs about Kernel Memory

For the functionality I will recommend reading [Kernel Docs for CGroups V1](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/memory.txt) instead of the docker docs:

> 2.7 Kernel Memory Extension (CONFIG_MEMCG_KMEM)
>
> With the Kernel memory extension, the Memory Controller is able to
> limit the amount of kernel memory used by the system. Kernel memory is
> fundamentally different than user memory, since it can't be swapped
> out, which makes it possible to DoS the system by consuming too much
> of this precious resource.
> [..]
>
> The memory used is
> accumulated into memory.kmem.usage_in_bytes, or in a separate counter
> when it makes sense. (currently only for tcp). The main "kmem" counter
> is fed into the main counter, so kmem charges will also be visible
> from the user counter.
>
> Currently no soft limit is implemented for kernel memory. It is future
> work to trigger slab reclaim when those limits are reached.

and

> 2.7.2 Common use cases
>
> Because the "kmem" counter is fed to the main user counter, kernel
> memory can never be limited completely independently of user memory.
> Say "U" is the user limit, and "K" the kernel limit. There are three
> possible ways limits can be set:
>
> ```
> U != 0, K = unlimited:
> This is the standard memcg limitation mechanism already present before kmem
> accounting. Kernel memory is completely ignored.
>
> U != 0, K < U:
> Kernel memory is a subset of the user memory. This setup is useful in
> deployments where the total amount of memory per-cgroup is overcommited.
> Overcommiting kernel memory limits is definitely not recommended, since the
> box can still run out of non-reclaimable memory.
> In this case, the admin could set up K so that the sum of all groups is
> never greater than the total memory, and freely set U at the cost of his
> QoS.
> WARNING: In the current implementation, memory reclaim will NOT be
> triggered for a cgroup when it hits K while staying below U, which makes
> this setup impractical.
>
> U != 0, K >= U:
> Since kmem charges will also be fed to the user counter and reclaim will be
> triggered for the cgroup for both kinds of memory. This setup gives the
> admin a unified view of memory, and it is also useful for people who just
> want to track kernel memory usage.
> ```

### Clumsy Attempt of a Conclusion

Given a running container with `--memory="2g" --memory-swap="2g" --oom-kill-disable` using

```
cat memory.kmem.max_usage_in_bytes
10747904
```

10 MB of Kernel-Memory in normal state. Would make sense to me to limit it, let's say to 20 MB of Kernel-Memory. Then it should kill or limit the container to protect the host. But due to the fact that there is - according to the docs - no possibility to reclaim the memory and the OOM Killer is starting to kill processes on host then even with a plenty of free memory (according to this: https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/1001) for me it is rather unpractical to use that.

The quoted option to set it `>= memory.limit_in_bytes` is not really helpful in that scenario either.

### Deprecated

`--kernel-memory` is deprecated in v20.10, due to the fact someone (=[Linux Kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/0158115f702b0ba208ab0b5adf44cae99b3ebcc7)) realized all that as well..

### What we can do then?

**ULimit**

Docker API exposes `HostConfig|Ulimit` which writes to `/etc/security/limits.conf`. For docker run should be `--ulimit <type>=<soft>:<hard>`. Use `cat /etc/security/limits.conf` or `man setrlimit` to see the categories and you can try to protect your system from filling kernel memory by e.g. generate unlimited processes with `--ulimit nproc=500:500`, but be careful, `nproc` works for users and not for containers, so count together..

To prevent DDoS (intentionally or unintentionally) i would suggest to limit at least `nofile` and `nproc`. Maybe someone can elaborate further..

**sysctl**:

`docker run --sysctl` can change kernel variables on [message queue](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/kernel.html#msgmax-msgmnb-and-msgmni) and [shared memory](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/kernel.html#shmmax), also [network](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/net.html), e.g. `docker run --sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_max_orphans=` for orphan tcp connections which defaults on my system to 131072, and by a kernel memory usage of 64 kB each: Bang 8 GB on malfunction or dos. Maybe someone can elaborate further..